# Login using laravel and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm learning laravel frameworking and I'm having issues with session in laravel and ajax(jquery). I can get authentication when the login form is submited but how to get session from laravel via ajax and access the dashboard panel?
Here it's my ajax requisition:

```
$(document).on("click", '#btn_login', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".msg_login").find('div').remove();

    var email = $("#email_login").val();
    var senha = $("#senha_login").val();
    var _token = $("#form_login input[name=_token]").val();

    if(email == '' || senha == '') {
        $(".msg_login").append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> Dados inválidos!</div>').fadeIn();
        $("#email_login").focus();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/login',
            data: {
                'email': email,
                'senha': senha,
                '_token': _token
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#btn_login").text('Acessando ...')
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data == '1') {
                    window.location.href = '/dashboard';
                } else if(data == 0) {
                    $(".msg_login").append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> Senha inválida</div>').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $(".msg_login").append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> Usuário não encontrado!</div>').fadeIn();
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
                $("#btn_login").text('Login')
            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".msg_login").fadeOut();
    }, 2500);
});
```

and here it's my controller:

```
public function find(Request $request) {
        $user = new academias;
        $user = $user::where('email', '=', $request->email)->get();
        $msg = '';

        if(count($user) > 0) {
            $senha = $user[0]->senha;

            if(Hash::check($request->senha, $senha)) {
                $msg = '1';
            } else {
                $msg = '0';
            }
        } else {
            $msg = '-1';
        }

        return $msg;
    }
```

As you see, if the user is found, the controller returns a value 1 and then the javascript redirects the use to the dashboard page but how can I create a session using ajax?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would try it in the find() function you posted, after the user login has been verified, start a session and set some variables

Comment: I've tried the find() too, but my question is exactly how to create the session and get it via ajax.